# Поменять местами первую и последнюю букву в слове

Tags: c#

Пробую написать консольную программу что бы в веденном слове первая и последняя буква поменялись местами.
К примеру слово "World" на выходе было "DorlW"
Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Можно сделать десятком способов. Какие методы для работы со строками вы знаете?

Comment: Ну я пока что додумался до StringBuilder.  Там есть Remove метод, пробовал через него, но только первый символ получилось поместить в конец слова.

Comment: Remove - это удаление, посмотрите на MSDN метод Substring, например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам ещё вариант, немного более короткий и с минимальными дополнительными аллокациями (одной):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
sb[0] = s[s.Length - 1];
sb[s.Length-1] = s[0];
return sb.ToString();
```

Работает для непустой строки `s`.

Ещё короче, но с двумя дополнительными аллокациями:

```
s.Last() + s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2) + s[0];
```

Comment: В первом примере, наверное, тоже 2 аллокации - создание SB, потом создание string из SB. И еще, что интересно - string не реализует IList, поэтому Last() (во втором примере) будет пробегать всё строку.

Comment: @Андрей: Угу, одна аллокация в любом случае нужна, так что в первом примере одна _дополнительная_ аллокация (кроме одной безусловно нужной).

Comment: @Андрей: Интересно, сколько аллокаций делает Last()?

Comment: [Ни одной, наверное?](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,965)

Comment: @Андрей: А `string.GetEnumerator()` не аллоцирует? // Таки аллоцирует: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,3431

Answer (score 5):

это рабочий пример. но в примере есть аллокация.

```
static string Change(string str)
{ 
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(str[str.Length - 1]);
    builder.Append(str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2));
    builder.Append(str[0]);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Скажите, откуда вы все знаете?:) Это практика или книги?

Comment: Чтобы не было дополнительных аллокаций, нужно вместо Substring использовать перегрузку с индексами: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc12ydtf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: И имеет смысл StringBuilder'у указать capacity в конструкторе.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо за комментарии . Я оставил здесь аллокация , не углублялся .)